# How to create validation on just one of the choices in a list column

Tags: 2013, column, validation

[image]I know I have done this before, but I am at a different company now and can't look up how I did it. I have created a Project Tracker list with several columns, including Status, % Complete, and Completion Date.

I want to allow the "Completed" choice for Status only if the `% Complete = 100`and the `Completion Date is not blank`. I am not sure exactly what to put in the formula field for Column Validation. I think it's something like this:

`[Status] = Completed if [% Complete] = 100% AND [Completion Date] = not blank`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `% Complete` field varies between 0 and 1. "Not blank" is represented by `NOT(ISBLANK(field))`

You can't do this under the column settings. You have to do it as a list validation. Go to List Settings, and under the General Settings section, click "Validation settings." Add this formula there:

`=IF(Status="Completed",AND([% Complete]=1,NOT(ISBLANK([Completion Date]))),TRUE)`

Comment: Hi Erin - Thanks very much for your answer. I am still having trouble. I pasted in exactly what you had, and got the same error. I then tried about 12 different variations (I am not a programmer, so the syntax is a bit hit and miss with me). This is the latest one I tried: [Status]=“Completed” if ([% Complete]=1,NOT(ISBLANK([Completion Date])),TRUE)  ..................... Can you please tell me what I need to change? I just want to make sure a person can't choose the Completed status unless they have marked 100% for % Complete and entered a Completion Date. Thanks again for your help! Norma

Comment: You can't use `if` the way you wrote. Did you include the equal sign at the beginning?  I tested this and don't get an error. Is your list a custom list, or did you start from a Tasks list?

Comment: Boss needs something; will try again shortly. Thanks.

Comment: I have a screen shot but I am not able to add it here...

Comment: Can you add it to your original post?

Comment: Just tried. Did it come through?

Comment: Yes. See the edits to my answer.

Comment: It looks as if my company blocked me from uploading the image.

Comment: I'm able to see it

Comment: OK, I guess they just blocked me from clicking on it again. I am not seeing edits to your answer (?)... Sorry. (By the way, this was a custom list.) - Oh, I see your update now. I'll try it right now.

Comment: You can't do this under the column settings. You have to do it as a list validation. Go to List Settings, and under the General Settings section, click "Validation settings." Add this formula there:

`=IF(Status="Completed",AND([% Complete]=1,NOT(ISBLANK([Completion Date]))),TRUE)`